# Architecture Tips: Business Logic / Data Access 

Tags: c#, architecture, business-logic

We plan to redesign, improve our (C#) application architecture.
Anyone has some framework, hompage or book recommendations?
Mainly concerning the business logic.

Comment: That's a very vague question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe look at [CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/)?

Its a framework that really builds around business objects. Buy the book and read it. Maybe its not the framework for you, but im sure it will give you some nice ideas about how to do it.